# How do I delete values from this document in MongoDB using Python

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am having a document which is structured like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564c0cb748f9fa2c8cdeb20f"),
    "username" : "blah",
    "useremail" : "blah@blahblah.com",
    "groupTypeCustomer" : true,
    "addedpartners" : [
        "562f1a629410d3271ba74f74",
        "562f1a6f9410d3271ba74f83"
    ],
    "groupName" : "Mojito",
    "groupTypeSupplier" : false,
    "groupDescription" : "A group for fashion designers"
}
```

Now I want to delete one of the values from this '`addedpartners`' array and update the document.
I want to just delete `562f1a6f9410d3271ba74f83` from the `addedpartners` array

This is what I had tried earlier.

```
db.myCollection.update({'_id':'564c0cb748f9fa2c8cdeb20f'},{'$pull':{'addedpartners':'562f1a6f9410d3271ba74f83'}})
```

Comment: Put the _id and addedpartners values in quotes, then it will works

Comment: Is ind query working for this query object? I think there's something wrong with your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.myCollection.update(
  { _id: ObjectId(id) },
  { $pull: { 'addedpartners': '562f1a629410d3271ba74f74' } }
);
```

Try with this

Comment: Soni ,  your answer is correct but it seems this is returning null value in python!

Answer (score -1):

```
db.myCollection.update({}, {$unset : {"addedpartners.1" : 1 }}) 
db.myCollection.update({}, {$pull : {"addedpartners" : null}})
```

No way to delete array directly, i think this is going to work, i haven't tried yet.

Comment: I have tried this as well, however your query makes changes to all the documents. You should not use {} in the first place without knowing its consequences.